# Shortest Distance Travelling Between Multiple Circles.

Tags: geometry, circles

I know that the shortest distance between two circles can be found by taking the distance between the centers of both circles and subtracting the radii but wanted to test if that idea stood for a set of more than 2 circles. My idea was to connect all of the circles by their center points (Treating these points as critical points) and between three of the circles find the point lying on the circumference of the middle circle that is directly between both of the lines connecting them.

A connection to a circle means that a critical point lies at some point inside or on the circumference of the circle.

For circles

$$C1: (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$$
$$C2: (x-4)^2+(y-4)^2=1$$
$$C3: (x-8)^2+(y-2)^2=1$$

The centers of all three circles can be connected by the lines
$$y-1=(x-1)$$
$$y-4=-\frac{1}{2}(x-4)$$

**These line segments connecting the circles should be in order of the circles given. i.e. C1 connects to C2 and C2 connects to C3. And should be continuous**

Then I connect the intersections of both lines and the middle circle $(x-4)^2+(y-4)^2=1$ making a chord with the line.
$$y-3.293=\frac{-0.26}{-1.601}(x-3.293)$$
After this I find the point in the center of the chord which is $(4.093,3.423)$. After that draw a line between the center of the chord and the center of the circle and extend it to the circumference of the circle and find it intersects at $(4.159,3.013)$ meaning that this point is the point on the center circle that will minimize the distance of line segments drawn between all of the circles.

I believe this logic works to find that shortest distance and then if I added more circles I would treat the newfound point (in this case $(4.159,3.013)$) as the critical point on the first circle in the set of 3 being used.

Does the logic hold up for more than 3 circles? Or will the critical point need to move in order to accommodate the changing of the critical point in the next circle.

Comment: Maybe, a preliminary step could be to generate the so-called "Delaunay triangulation" associated with the set of circles' centers.

Comment: How are you defining the distance between three circles?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel the distance between the three circles is the sum of the length of line segments connected by the critical points. At the start the critical points are the centers of each circle and the problem has to do with changing these critical points to minimize the lengths of these line segments. I edited the question to be more clear about how they are connected.

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think so considering that the set of circles' centers is only used for defining the circles and likely will not be the final critical points used in calculating the distance.